# Bash script file not found

Tags: linux, bash

```
echo 'Sum'
awk '!found[$1]++' file.txt file2.txt | sort -n
echo 'A\B:'
sort file2.txt file2.txt file.txt | uniq -u
```

It just prints like 3 errors, file not found, command not found, 'ort wrong option', 'niq wrong option', whatever 'niq' and 'ort' are. Does it have some syntax errors or i need to install some packages? It all worked fine on cygwin on Windows.

Comment: `dos2unix myScript` . Also check that `/usr/bin/` is part of your `$PATH` variable (if it's not something is wrong). Good luck.

Comment: You're missing `#!/bin/bash` at the top. Alternatively run with `bash "/path/to/script"`